# Nestjs - Possible to get properly instantiated body payload?

Tags: nestjs, dto

Nestjs documentation advises to use classes instead of interfaces for the DTO's because `they are preserved as real entities in the compiled JavaScript` but in reality the payload classes are not properly instantiated (with new()), they are  Objects with the same shape as the class.
The below example does not work.
Is there a way to get a properly instantiated runtime `CatDto` class in the example ?

```
class CatsDto {
  constructor(private name: string) {}
  public greet() {
    return `${this.name} say miaouw`;
  }
}

@Controller()
export class AppController {
  constructor(private readonly appService: AppService) {}

  @Post()
  getGreeting(@Body() cat: CatsDto): string {
    return cat.greet();
  }
}
```

Comment: Is [class-transformer](https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer) installed in your `package.json` ? What is the result of `cat.greet()` ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the ClassTransformer pipe to transform objects that are passed as arguments of your controller actions: https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/validation#transform-payload-objects